# How to select only distinct row when there might be duplicates using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a tricky SQL query I could use some help with.

I have a phone directory table, that was not designed very well.  It has name, phone number, job description and primary_job_indicator.  However, the primary_job_indicator isn't doing it's job.  Not everyone has a primary_job.

Here's some sample data:

```
  fname     lname     phone     email           job          primary_job_ind
  Tim       Burton    222-2222  tburton@ok.com  manager      Y
  Jim       Classy    222-3333  tclassy@ok.com  instructor   Y
  Jim       Classy    222-3333  tclassy@ok.com  dept head    N
  Jane      Dill      222-4444  jdill@ok.com    janitor      N
```

I would like to select only the following, one row, with one job per person :

```
  Tim Burton    222-2222  tburton@ok.com  manager
  Jim classy    222-3333  jclassy@ok.com  instructor
  Jane Dill     222-4444  jdill@ok.com    janitor
```

I want to select from the table and avoid duplicate name+phone number+email.

If the person has only one row in the table, I want to select that row.

If the person has more than one row in the table, I want to select only one row - the one with primary_job_ind = 'Y' if it exists

I can't figure out how to do it :

```
SELECT fname, lname, phone, email, job
FROM phonedirectory
WHERE  (( primary_job_ind = 'Y' ) OR ??????? )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is no typo (which there probably is), this should do the job

```
select fname, lname, phone, email, job
from (
    SELECT fname, lname, phone, email, job,
        row_number() over (
            partition by fname, lname, phone, email
            order by primary_job_ind desc
        ) r
    FROM phonedirectory
) where r = 1
```

It numbers the rows, belonging to the same person, with the primary job first, then takes only the first row for each person.

[See the documenation of ROW_NUMBER for details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100)

Comment: Jens is fast and the answer is perfect. I was tad late. SQLFiddle example is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9c4d/6). Jens has an additional paranthesis after phonedirectory that has been corrected in the fiddle.